# Error when installing ige-mac-integration on Mac

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, gtk

I installed `GTK` for `Mac OS` by followed command:

```
port install gtk2 +quartz +no_x11
```

but got error: `Error: org.macports.archivefetch for port gtk2 returned: cairo must be installed with +quartz.`

So I installed `cairo` and `pango` with `+quartz` flag:

```
port install cairo +no_x11 +quartz
port install pango +no_x11 +quartz
```

After I reinstalled `GTK` and it has installed successfully.

But when I try to install `ige-mac-integration` get error:

```
port install ige-mac-integration

--->  Fetching archive for py27-pygtk
Error: org.macports.archivefetch for port py27-pygtk returned: gtk2 must be installed with +x11.
```

but I need `GTK` without `x11`

What should i do?

Thanks,

Comment: I can only say that I have the exact same problem. I also tried installing py27-pygtk +quartz but that failed too... Let me know if you have found a fix...

Comment: Sounds like its deprecated, use `gtk-osx-application` instead : `port install gtk2 +quartz +no_x11` and 
`port install gtk-osx-application -python27`

Comment: Unfortunately, some ports (eg gobby) still depend on ige-mac-integration

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `ige-mac-integration` is deprecated,

use `gtk-osx-application` instead:

```
port install gtk2 +quartz +no_x11
```

after

```
port install gtk-osx-application -python27
```